# Fast inner product of ternary vectors

Tags: c++, c, vector, product

Consider two vectors, **A** and **B**, of size *n*, 7 <= *n* <= 23. Both **A** and **B** consists of -1s, 0s and 1s only.

I need a fast algorithm which computes the inner product of **A** and **B**.

So far I've thought of storing the signs and values in separate `uint32_t`s using the following encoding:

- sign 0, value 0 → 0
- sign 0, value 1 → 1
- sign 1, value 1 → -1.

The C++ implementation I've thought of looks like the following:

```
struct ternary_vector {
    uint32_t sign, value;
};

int inner_product(const ternary_vector & a, const ternary_vector & b) {
    uint32_t psign = a.sign ^ b.sign;
    uint32_t pvalue = a.value & b.value;
    psign &= pvalue;
    pvalue ^= psign;
    return __builtin_popcount(pvalue) - __builtin_popcount(psign);
}
```

This works reasonably well, but I'm not sure whether it is possible to do it better. Any comment on the matter is highly appreciated.

Comment: uint32_t for a variable that can have only 1 of 3 values seems, ah, excessive...

Comment: @ScottHunter He's storing the entire vector in two `uint32_t` variables.  Each vector element consumes one bit of `sign` and one bit of `value`.  Remember that his vectors have a maximum length of 23.

Comment: I can not think of a faster implementation right now. Your idea is good. Only thing I can think of is: how fast is it to build the vectors in this format?

Answer (score 3):

I like having the 2 `uint32_t`, but I think your actual calculation is a bit wasteful

Just a few minor points:

- I'm not sure about the reference (getting `a` and `b` by `const &`) - this adds a level of indirection compared to putting them on the stack. When the code is this small (a couple of clocks maybe) this is significant. Try passing by value and see what you get
- `__builtin_popcount` can be, unfortunately, very inefficient. I've used it myself, but found that even a very basic implementation I wrote was far faster than this. However - this is dependent on the platform.

Basically, if the platform has a hardware popcount implementation, `__builtin_popcount` uses it. If not - it uses a very inefficient replacement.

Comment: +1 for "pass by value". I was going to mention that. [See this article](http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/08/want-speed-pass-by-value/).

Comment: If the function is inlined, the pass-by-reference will not matter. If the function is not inlined, the function call overhead will be greater than the indirection overhead.

Comment: @cluracan
1. Passing by value doesn't have any effect. Though I haven't checked the assembly, I suppose that the code is inlined.
2. The target platform supports hardware popcount.

Comment: @user92382 I just checked on my computer, and it seems that the optimizer indeed translates the "pass by reference" to "pass by value". So no luck there. However, the `__builtin_popcount` was indeed a function call which isn't what you want here. Make sure it isn't like that on your platform. Especially since you do want to do 2 popcounts, this may be greatly improved by doing it yourself (as you can optimize for both together). But first you'll have to check for yourself if it's a function call or assembly instruction :)

Answer (score 0):

The one serious problem here is the reuse of the `psign` and `pvalue` variables for the positive and negative vectors. You are doing neither your compiler nor yourself any favors by obfuscating your code in this way.

Comment: The _obfuscation_ doesn't seem to affect the speed in any way.

Answer (score 0):

Would it be possible for you to encode your ternary state in a `std::bitset<2>` and define the product in terms of `and`? For example, if your ternary types are:

```
 1 = P = (1, 1)
 0 = Z = (0, 0)
-1 = M = (1, 0) or (0, 1)
```

I believe you could define their product as:

```
1 *  1 =  1 => P * P = P => (1, 1) & (1, 1) = (1, 1) = P
1 *  0 =  0 => P * Z = Z => (1, 1) & (0, 0) = (0, 0) = Z
1 * -1 = -1 => P * M = M => (1, 1) & (1, 0) = (1, 0) = M
```

Then the inner product could start by taking the and of the bits of the elements and... I am working on how to add them together.

#### Edit:

My foolish suggestion did not consider that `(-1)(-1) = 1`, which cannot be handled by the representation I proposed. Thanks to @user92382 for bringing this up.

Comment: I don't really see how to get a (-1)*(-1)=1 with your representation and the `and` operator.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your architecture, you may want to optimize away the temporary bit vectors -- e.g. if your code is going to be compiled to FPGA, or laid out to an ASIC, then a sequence of logical operations will be better in terms of speed/energy/area than storing and reading/writing to two big buffers.

In this case, you can do:

```
int inner_product(const ternary_vector & a, const ternary_vector & b) {
   return __builtin_popcount( a.value & b.value & ~(a.sign ^ b.sign))
      -   __builtin_popcount( a.value & b.value &  (a.sign ^ b.sign));  
}
```

This will lay out very well -- the (a.value & b.value & ... ) can enable/disable an XOR gate, whose output splits into two signed accumulators, with the first pathway NOTed before accumulation.